# Line under the function showing scope

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know exactly the name of this, so I don't know what I'm searching for. I saw in some programming videos that when the cursor is inside a function it shows a line that goes under the function and then down until the end of the function scope (like in the image below).

[image]

[image]

is this an extention or a setting? how can i enable it? Can someone please help me?

Comment: Looks hand drawn to me. Like the person who made the video drew it.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i did it to show how it look like

Comment: bracket pair colorizer, it is now build in, search the settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was apparently [implemented recently](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136475) (2021/22). I'm running `v1.68.1` and it is available. The new setting is actually called `bracketPairsHorizontal`. If that is false, the horizontal line won't show.
Edit your `settings.json` file and add the following:

```
// Bracket-pair guides
"editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
"editor.guides.bracketPairsHorizontal": true,       // shows horizontal line
"editor.guides.highlightActiveBracketPair": true,   // highlight both horizontal and vertical lines

// Bracket-pair colorization
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false, 
"editor.bracketPairColorization.independentColorPoolPerBracketType": true,

// Indentation lines
"editor.guides.indentation": true                   // shows vertical lines
```

Some settings depend on each other, ex. `bracketPairs` will override `indentation`.
Result with above settings:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

as @rioV8 said in the comments, it is a setting called `Editor › Guides: Bracket Pairs`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

step 1: settings

step 2: type-> guides [Guides: Bracket Pairs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxzHU.png)

step 3:

```
    if you want to highlight your scope or bracket pair colorizer 
    -> true/active

    If you don't want to highlight your scope or bracket pair colorizer
    -> false
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).